# Unity object initialization synchronization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, initialization

Until now, I've been coding thinking that functions in `monobehaviour` would be executed in this order:

> OnEnable > Start > Update > OnDisable

The problem is that I thought that this order would be **absolute**, meaning that until a function is not completely finished, there's no way that the next one would start being executed.

1. So first question is: Is that true? Would `update` NOT be executed until `start` ends?

Then my problem arises with synchronization between different `monobehaviour` classes.

I have a class that creates some objects (a Menu basically) in its `start` function. Then in a different class, I've a similar code, but it also **depends** on the object created by the first class to exist already. I'm getting an error because the object is not found yet.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ShopHandler.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Shops/ShopHandler.cs:60)

So now I'm stuck with this. Therefore my second question would be,

2. How can I **synchronize my different classes when they depend on others like this**?

Finally, a question mixed from these two also has to be asked:

3. Would `update` function be executed in any of these classes, while they're somehow "waiting" for their initialization part, be it in `start` function, `OnEnable` function or whatever?

Because of course, `update` function relies on objects being initialized already, and this could end in new problems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include errors and exception messages in your question as text, not as images. Including them as images makes questions harder to find by search for people with similar problems and also makes the question less accessible for people who use screen readers.

Comment: Also, it's recommended to separate questions with multiple parts [into separate posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say where your problem is actually coming from, because you have not posted any code. However, I believe your problem might be solved by implementing solution noted at `2`

1. Yes, All Start Functions (and Awake) are called before the update function, **if the gameobjects/ monobehaviours are enabled/active! Start/Awake/Update are not called on inactive gameobjects**
2. You should look into `Script Execution Order`. Here you can make sure that the start/ awake/ update functions of classes are called in a certain order. It should be listed under project settings.
3. When initializing a scene, update will be called after all awake/ start functions have finished (unless they are defined as Coroutines, but this is probably not your issue).

Comment: Seems good. I'm going to take a look at it. Will come back with news. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach:

Let's say you have two monobehaviours A and B. Assume that B has to initialised after A. Then;

1-) Create a function, i.e "Initialise" and use it in B instead of the Start function:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class B : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void Initialise()
    {
        //Code you run on Start()    
    }

}
```

2-) Reference B obj in A obj, use bObj.Initialise after are ready to initialise it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    public B bObj;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Things to do in Start()
        //...
        //...
        //...
        bObj.Initialise();
    }

}
```

Lastly, if you want your Update function run whenever you want, I usually prefer to use something as a flag. So here's my second version of class B for controlling update() behavior:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canUpdate;
    public void Initialise()
    {
        //Code you run on Start()
        canUpdate = true;    
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (canUpdate)
        {
            //do the stuff
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I was expecting some kind of overhead when starting to read the method, but it seems rather clean (to me at least). Thanks man.

Comment: Happy to hear that! ; )

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I thought that this order would be absolute, meaning that until a function is not completely finished, there's no way that the next one would start being executed.
>
> > So first question is: Is that true? Would update NOT be executed until start ends?

Usually yes, but there is an exception.

If you implement `Start` as a coroutine, `Update` can be called before `Start` ends on the same monobehaviour.

For instance, this code:

```
IEnumerator Start() 
{
    Debug.Log("Start beginning");
    
    yield return null;

    Debug.Log("Start continuing");

    yield return null;

    Debug.Log("Start completing");    
}

void Update() 
{
    Debug.Log("Update running");
}
```

Could produce this output:

> Start beginning
> Start continuing
> Update running
> Start completing
> Update running
> Update running
> Update running
> ...

Comment: For clarrification can the normal `(private) void Start()` be replaced with a `(private) IEnumerator Start()`?

Comment: internal is not the same as not putting an access modifier infront of a/ the function. private is the default. (To check this, you could try calling the start method from another class with and without the internal modifier within the same namespace, to see the difference)

Comment: thanks- @akaBase, Yes, they could be protected public or internal as well